# Open .obj in Azure Error

Tags: azure, webgl, mime, .obj

When I open `.obj` file in Windows Azure running Windows Server 2008 using Google chrome it gives error 
(eg: localhost/obj/test.obj)

The error is shown below, may I know how can I solve this problem?

``` HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found. The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the ``page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map. ```